# Is a question about the Shetar Mechirat Chametz appropriate on J.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I am in need of your help on a project that I am working on. I am attempting to translate the Yiddish phrases which can be found in the document used to sell chametz to a non-Jew into Hebrew. The document I am working with, by HRH"G Avraham Aharon Yudelewitz ztz"l (author of Shu"t Bet Av), is sprinkled with Yiddish phrases which I do not understand.

Would a request for translation of certain phrases be acceptable on J.SE or is it considered out of scope or too local? If it is unacceptable on the website, may I post it in chat?

Answer (score 4):

As far as scope (topicality) goes, it seems to me that it's within the scope of the site. [The FAQ list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) specifically allows "questions about... language used in Jewish life and learning".

It's not a very strong question (just seeking translation), but I think it's a valid one for the site.

Comment: It seems this decision was implemented here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15291/759